# Truth value of conclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Here I are premises followed by a conclusion. I want to confirm if my understanding about conclusion being false is right or not. In the book it was mentioned that their conclusion is false.

My understanding about first premises is: 
"having access to network does not mean you can change grade"
So I am guessing that to find out if conclusion is true or not we compare it with real life situation. If in reality it can happen then its true otherwise not. Am I right about it?

“If you have access to the network, then you can change your grade.”
“You have access to the network.”

---

∴ “You can change your grade.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It his simply an instance of *modus ponens* :

> > from $p$ and $p \rightarrow q$, infer $q$.

Your $p$ is : "You have access to the network”.

Your $p \rightarrow q$ is : "If you have access to the network, then you can change your grade”.

Thus, you are licensed to infer :

> > $q$, i.e."You can change your grade".

Comment: But this only means arguments are valid. I am asking about conclusion being true or false

Comment: @user3461957 - *modus ponens* is "sound", i.e. it allows us to infer a *true* conclusion from *true* premises. **If** your premises : "If you have access to the network, then you can change your grade” and "You have access to the network” are true, then also the conclusion must be.

Comment: @user3461957 - are you sure about your "translation" of the original problem ? Of course, from the single premise : "If you have access to the network, then you can change your grade” you are **not** allowed to conclude that "You can change your grade". In this case, your conclusion is the right one. According to the truth-functional interpretation of the *conditional*, $p \rightarrow q$ is *true* also when $p$ is *false*.